# Operator in variable Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, operators

I am trying to make a function to see if all my textfields are filled in, I pass it an array, Let's say `var array = ["1", "2", "3"]`

And I want to check the if statement `if array[0].isEmpty || array[1].isEmpty || array[2].isEmpty`

But it has to be variable, so I thought about using a for loop and using the operator as a variable, that doesn't work, at least not how I am doing it, does anyone have an idea for this?

```
var op = false
    
    for field in array {
        op += field.isEmpty
        op += ||
    }
    
    if op {
        
    }
```

Kind regards
Daan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
array.allSatisfy{ !$0.isEmpty } // false => means that one or more items is/are empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the check as

```
array.first(where: \.isEmpty) != nil
```

As suggested by @MartinR in the comments you can use `contains` instead which makes it a bit neater and with the same performance

```
array.contains(where: \.isEmpty)
```

Comment: Or simply `array.contains(where: \.isEmpty)`

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked for me! But the one above suits my code more ;)) Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @DaanHermans I see now you want a variable, not sure why I read it as it should be a property